# Syntax error comparing "If" statements

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a banking application that has a monthly constant service fee of $10 and charges people a certain amount of money per number of checks they deposit. For anything under 20 checks, they're charged $0.10, between 20 and 39, $0.08 etc etc. I am having a syntax error in my "If" statements creating the logic for the program. Can anyone explain why? Here is the code

```
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    Dim bankCharge As Integer = 10
    Dim checks1 As Decimal = 0.1
    Dim checks2 As Decimal = 0.08
    Dim checks3 As Decimal = 0.06
    Dim checks4 As Decimal = 0.04

    Dim checks As Double
    If Not Integer.TryParse(txtCheckBox.Text, checks) Then
        MessageBox.Show("This is not a number!")
    End If

    If txtCheckBox.Text < 20 Then
        (checks * checks1 + bankCharge = lblFeeTotal) 'the error starts HERE
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: turn on `Option Strict` - `txtCheckBox.Text < 20` is testing a string against an integer.  You are also trying to use Integer.Parse to save to a Double.

Comment: Your use of paranthesis is questionable.  Is lblFeeTotal supposed to equal something?

Comment: lblFeeTotal is where the total service charge fee would display. Say they deposited 25 checks, they would be charged $0.08 per check on top of the $10 monthly service fee.

Comment: Right.  So wouldn't that be `lblFeeTotal.Text = your number`?  If checks is not a number, you need to exit the routine.  You still continue after the message is displayed.  It should also be `If checks < 20 Then` since checks is your number.  Make a decision: is checks a decimal, an integer, or a double?

Comment: Plutonix - The syntax error appears at the first parenthesis at the second If statement. If I remove the parenthesis, then I get another error saying the "expression is not a method"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement is back to front

> (checks * checks1 + bankCharge = lblFeeTotal) 'the error starts HERE

It should be written as

> lblFeeTotal = (checks * checks1 + bankCharge )

And if lblFeeTotal is a LABEL CONTROL
Then you could write it as....

> lblFeeTotal.text = (checks * checks1 + bankCharge )

Answer (score 0):

If you are assigning the value lblFeeTotal, then the code is backwards. Try with

```
lblFeeTotal = (checks * checks1 + bankCharge)
```

Assuming lblFeeTotal exists and is a variable for calculation. If it's for display (eg: a textbox), then the code is:

```
lblFeeTotal.Text = (checks * checks1 + bankCharge)
```